# User Created and granted privileges in sqlplus but from SqlDeveloper not connect

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, sqlplus

I have an Oracle 21c XE by Docker on Ubuntu 20.04. I created a user from the system and gave it to connect and resource privileges from sqlplus and I am able to connect from sqlplus but with the same credentials, I am not able to connect from SqlDeveloper. It's showing me an invalid username/password but I double-checked and the username and password are correct.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to connect to the wrong database.

In SQL Developer you have

```
SID: XE
```

But in SQLPlus you are connecting to

```
Service: XEPDB1
```

So make your SQL Developer connection like this -

[image]